# Forward wildcard subdomain to same subdomain on different domain

Tags: domain-name-system

It looks like there's a few similar questions but they all seem to want to do this through various HTTP redirects, and I'm looking to do this purely through DNS.

Basically I'm trying to forward all subdomains of a given domain so they resolve to the same-named subdomain of another domain.

E.g.

```
*.foo.com -> *.bar.com
```

Therefore any domain would resolve:

```
blah.foo.com -> blah.bar.com
garbage123.foo.com -> garbage123.bar.com
maybe.ifimlucky.foo.com -> maybe.ifimlucky.bar.com
```

I'm looking for a product-agnostic solution. Is this possible, or am I stuck wiring up each subdomain manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [DNAME record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6672.txt) may suffice for this redirect, though I don't know how it will handle sub-sub domains (your `maybe.ifimlucky` example). On the other hand, DNAME records can be very surprising, so ideally would need to be extensively documented (that is, edits to a zone with a DNAME record in it will show a serial change, but still forward elsewhere, so if folks don't know that's going on...)

Comment: That looks spot on: "[...] for the domain name "foo.example.com", and a DNAME resource record is found at "example.com" indicating that all queries under "example.com" be directed to "example.net".  The lookup process will return to step 1 with the new query name of "foo.example.net".  Had the query name been "www.foo.example.com", the new query name would be "www.foo.example.net"."

Comment: However, it can be *very* surprising, hence my warnings (I learned about it the hard way, in that requested zone updates to another group "didn't work" and much head scratching ensued).

Comment: Good to know. Currently I'm in exploratory mode so I'm just looking at whether it can even be done.